# Typescript array of generic types

Tags: typescript

I want to do something like this:

```
type Item<T> = T & {
  func: (v: T) => void
}

function a<What>(...items: Item<What>[]) {}

a({
  name: "",
  func: (v: {name: string}) => {}
}, {
  count: 0,
  func: (v: {count: number}) => {}
})
```

However above code will cause an error, how to do the similar thing with typscript?

Comment: What should be `What` in your case?

Comment: ah, it's different for every item?

Comment: Yes, as you see, `What` is a generic parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize a syntax like this:

```
function a<T extends any[]>(...items: { 
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] & { func: (v: Omit<T[K], 'func'>) => void } 
}) {}
```

A mapped type can be used to map over each element in `items`. `T[K]` always represents the current element, so we can use it to intersect itself with the function object.

```
// ok
a({
  name: "",
  func: (v: { name: string }) => {}
}, {
  count: 0,
  func: (v: { count: number }) => {}
})

// error
a({
  name: 0,
  func: (v: { name: string }) => {} /*
  ~~~~ Types of property 'name' are incompatible 
*/ 
}, {
  count: 0,
  func: (v: { count: number }) => {}
})
```

For the implementation of the function, I would recommend to put all the complex generic stuff in an overload and to use a simpler signature for the implementing function.

```
function b<T extends any[]>(...items: { 
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] & { func: (v: Omit<T[K], 'func'>) => void } 
}): void
function b(...items: ({ func: (arg: object) => void } & Record<string, any>)[]) {
  for (const item of items) {
    item.func({})
  }
}
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAgIYB4AqyCmAPGHCAEwGc0IBPAbQF0A+ACgDpW5CBbUgLmQG9kwZMmoBpZHBQBrHJQQhkmWr0xjayAGT9k4aL0YA3XgHkO7LGoA0yAOS6oN+gEpkAXnrIDCOMWQBfQT8XPj9gYAB6cOQEKWBURj4hZAhUDhxeACIMyyT7fSNtFLTeUhgAJ0kAc38Xd35Qv2tE4SgESBheAAYc4TzkQ14BVvbeCDAOACMcMpq3DxDgILDI3DKyhDK4hKSi9ORu3MgofMHk1L3SiohqoLn65HCAKiSAPzeXxUoABxxyeWQvusfmUYJRbLsbGgyjgJNAEBwvqh4BMADYw4CPKKLJpJYYQDr7Ho6I4nbR4gljSbTWZ1BZLUBHeBIZATLC4AhEMgUGgMFhsTg8bRJMSw5AyOQKJQqNSabR9AbIUzmVSiWjWOxHRy1DxeHz+QJOXi64gM6BMlATPnMdg4Lj6ATy1BlSq8BATABWOFg2s83l8AS0ACUvRtiOhLlVrKgqM46MFcht+q0IKUJJxogobVx48JhFnmPYEkthA0gA)

Comment: funnily enough, your solution allows to pass an additional property `func` in v, `func: (v: { name: string, func: any }) => {}` but prohibits all other properties, also inside the function `a` elements of items get inferred as `any` due to the index signature, but thats at least better than my solution which infers them as `never` 

Comment: Yeah, we should probably `Omit` the function from `T[K]`.

Answer (score 2):

I almost have it, however i cant get function to infer the generic on its own, but im sharing this anyway, in case someone else might solve it, or in case this helps you nontheless.

The trick i used to is to recursively infer each Item of `What`, that way `What` is properly handled as tuple and the Item constraint is applied to each element in `What` seperately.

```
type Item<T> =
    T & {func(v:T):void}

type Items<What> =
    What extends [Item<infer A>, ...infer Rest]
    ? [Item<A>,...Items<[...Rest]>]
    : What extends [] ? [] : never

function testFunction<What>(...items: Items<What>) {}

//this works, with an explicit generic
testFunction<[Item<{
    name: string;
}>, Item<{
    count: number;
}>]>({
  name: "",
  func: (v: {name: string}) => {}
}, {
  count: 0,
  func: (v: {count: number}) => {}
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=23&ssc=3&pln=2&pc=1#code/FAFwngDgpgBAkiKBbAPAFQHwwLzBvmNGAMhgG8AzAVwDsBjACgDcAuNAShaYHsBLAEwC%20wUJFgJkAZxQB1ABYBDEFlwEY8pTCgAPRDX6SYAbQmpeNClABOMAIIYANDAB0r85ZsAlKJJABdPAIAfmNTFHsHV2dTaSMo718-DAC1FnVFEC1dKH1DIz8YEPyYNJooJmsRanoQXm4aGERfADFaOlr62QyMBijeRCRJNJiupQx2cmFgAHppkDleQwB3bisAa0knJf65GAUGnQgAG146fpgAcxzrU9AfEFaaupoUEwGUMkD8GgUkKDTfFZzBcANzAQSOeDvT5qOjcWggUpUJAAI2sYIhSQYMJgPz%20aQARASHIFqnQ0sw0mQ8f8YIDgYIJtgsGRhIInDi4Qi0gAGEn4MkU1jkLk0RG45FoqyMnAstnsESzeaLOncP5ybhLGD8bg%20MVOfb8S5QECGdzWKxQI0gbgwWhrGiamgiJoPNodGjYwI0wnE0ltIVUn10kBAmgXGXMybgjmBUXivn%20%20iBkXwsVI1HWSNy8EKmbTJYLI6wUTQRr3OAWC1WnBQqSvHHBon8mCCmCU8jB%20nh7PR9nkONphMttsdsjxjNS3us8FJMGzGAq8z8KA1%20awSS-WAKSSl2DmqyWo3YULQr64rcA0PAjGQsI4-ATiWZqy3vxAA)

Answer (score -1):

```
type Item<T> = T & {
  func: (v: T) => void
}

function a<A extends Item<any>[]>(...items: A) {}

a({
  name: "",
  func: (v: {name: string}) => {}
}, {
  count: 0,
  func: (v: {count: number}) => {}
})
// ^?
// function a<[{
//     name: string;
//     func: (v: {
//         name: string;
//     }) => void;
// }, {
//     count: number;
//     func: (v: {
//         count: number;
//     }) => void;
// }]>(items_0: {
//     name: string;
//     func: (v: {
//         name: string;
//     }) => void;
// }, items_1: {
//     count: number;
//     func: (v: {
//         count: number;
//     }) => void;
// }): void
```

Comment: This is wrong, it doenst ensure that each argument satisfies the Item constraint, `Item<any>` collapses to `any` so youre essentially saying, `function a<A extends any[]>(...items: A){}`